# TFS edit build log using custom activity

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In TFS while we fire a build. the build log is generated with all the details. like testcases result, code analysis etc...

How do I add some more details in build log? Which API need to be used to edit build log from custom activity?

Please provide me some article links if possible.