# TFS 2010 Show Output In Log Window

Tags: tfs, workflow, build-process

I have a custom activity and I'd like to show some messages during build process. How can I do that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077396/tfs-edit-build-log-using-custom-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-8-Send-information-to-the-build-log.aspx) post by E.Hofman.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Customize Team Build 2010 – Part 13: Get control over the Build Output by Ewald Hofman](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/10/02/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-13-Get-control-over-the-Build-Output.aspx)

And the other part [Part 8: Send information to the build log?](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/28/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-8-Send-information-to-the-build-log.aspx).